# A good Mail Server tutorial?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, email-server

I recently got a VPS and is in the process of making it into a web server. I got everything setup but mail. I've been working on this mail server for a bit, but I haven't had much time to work on it. When I do though, I try to use a tutorial. But each one has seem to have caused an issue so I would wipe the server and start over. Recently, I was following this [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixCompleteVirtualMailSystemHowto) and it seemed promising, but then when I tried to send mail it would just freeze up and I would have to stop and start apache. My knowledge of linux is very limited, but I'm trying to learn. So far linux has been good, and I really like it, but mail has been the last thing that has stopped me. I'm currently running Ubuntu 10.04 x64.

Is there a tutorial that you would recommend for Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: Exactly that tutorial you failed on. You should really try again and then tell **what** did not work. "Freeze" is not analyzable.

Comment: Asking for tutorials is generally not a good idea, as the tutorials get out of date quickly, and are of little use to future visitors. Instead, if you have a specific question about where you're stuck, feel free to [ask another question](http://serverfault.com/questions/ask) outlining exactly where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For server configuration I can recommend either the [Linode](http://library.linode.com/) or [Slicehost](http://articles.slicehost.com/) tutorials. For emails, you might find what you want here:

- [Linode: Email Server Guides](http://library.linode.com/email)
- [Slicehost: Barebones postfix install for Ubuntu](http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/3/1/barebones-postfix-install-for-ubuntu)

Those sites cover plenty of other topics, and are fairly easy to understand, even for a linux novice.

Answer (score 0):

Best installation script and mail system ever iRedMail

http://www.iredmail.org/install_iredmail_on_ubuntu.html

its simple and very powerfull